# Too many options error when using SQL commands in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I'm automating some tasks and ran into an issue that I haven't been able figure out.  Basically I'm trying to run database queries that use keys in Powershell.  Example:

```
.\SQLite.exe -key $key $database < $commandsTXT
```

However I'm forced to use this expression because Powershell doesn't like spaces and the < character.

```
.\SQLite.exe -key `"$key`" `"$database`" `"<`" `"$commandsTXT`"
```

I have two questions. 1) Can I make this less ugly? 2) Why am I getting the error, "Too many options".

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
gc $commandsTXT | & .\SQLite.exe -key $key $database
```

This will pipe the contents of `$commandsTXT` into SQLite. I'm assuming `$key` and `$database` are strings.